# R studio Function to sample a value from Weibull distribution

Tags: statistics

I need to write a function that obtains a sampled value from a Weibull distribution with parameters $\phi$ and k.

After using cdf inversion method, I get that $\frac{1}{\phi} \{ -\log (1-U) \}^{1/k}$ is distributed with Weibull($\phi$, k) distribution (where $U$ is the Uniform(0, 1) distribution.

I wrote the following code:

```
Weib_sim <- function(phi, k)
{
  u = runif(1)
  sample.value = (1/phi)*(-log(1-u))^((1/k))
  return(sample.value)
}
```

But I compared my function with `rweibull` function in R and it seems to give significantly different results with same parameters. Could you please help me correct my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an issue of the parameters you are using in your function and in R.

It seems that your $\phi$ is the rate, i.e. the reciprocal of the scale, while your $k$ is the shape. The R function uses the shape and scale in that order. Very slightly adapting your code to produce $n$ values rather than $1$, and then comparing taking into account the reciprocal and order, the distributions look the same to me.

```
Weib_sim <- function(n, phi, k)
{
  u = runif(n)
  sample.value = (1/phi)*(-log(1-u))^((1/k))
  return(sample.value)
}

Weib_sim_example <- Weib_sim(n=10^4, phi=2, k=3)
rweibull_example <- rweibull(n=10^4, shape=3, scale=1/2)
plot.ecdf(Weib_sim_example)
plot.ecdf(rweibull_example, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

gives

[image: ecdf]